# Como criar um array dentro de outro array com jQuery

Tags: javascript, array

Estou tentando criar um `array` em `jQuery` utilizando a função .push() onde cada elemento deverá conter um outro `array` dentro dele. A estrutura que eu preciso criar é essa:

```
 
array(
    'elemento1' => array(
        'elemento1' => 'dado1',
        'elemento2' => 'dado2'
    ),
    'elemento2' => array(
        'elemento1' => 'dado1',
        'elemento2' => 'dado2'
    ),
    'elemento1' => array(
        'elemento1' => 'dado1',
        'elemento2' => 'dado2'
    ),
)
```

A minha intenção é gerar uma lista de informações com as faturas de uma NF-e, onde cada fatura terá o seu número de fatura, data de vencimento e o valor dela. Com isso eu quero gerar um array no jquery para passar via ajax como parâmetro e no arquivo php, fazer todo o tratamento para ser gravado no mysql. Basicamente é isso.

Como proceder?

Comment: Bruno vi o teu fiddle agora, tem alguns erros simples de resolver. Podes dar um exmplo de como queres usar essa array? assim fica mais fácil acertar na resposta.

Comment: A minha intenção é gerar uma lista de informações com as faturas de uma `NF-e`, onde cada fatura terá o seu número de fatura, data de vencimento e o valor dela. Com isso eu quero gerar um `array` no `jquery` para passar via `ajax` como parâmetro e no arquivo php, fazer todo o tratamento para ser gravado no `mysql`. Basicamente é isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUÇÃO**
A solução que eu encontrei foi essa: https://jsfiddle.net/2p4yvoue/1/

Answer (score 6):

Tem várias maneiras. A mais próxima do código que você colocou (que é PHP, né?), são objetos literais aninhados (se as chaves tiverem nomes), ou arrays aninhados (chaves numéricas).

#### Objetos literais aninhados

```
var obj = {
    'elemento1' : {
        'elemento1' : 'dado1',
        'elemento2' : 'dado2'
    },
    'elemento2' : {
        'elemento1' : 'dado1',
        'elemento2' : 'dado2'
    },
    'elemento1' : {
        'elemento1' : 'dado1',
        'elemento2' : 'dado2'
    },
};
```

#### Arrays literais aninhados

```
var arr = [
    ['dado1','dado2'],
    ['dado1','dado2'],
    ['dado1','dado2']
];
```

Ou talvez você queira uma combinação entre os dois, como na [resposta do Eduardo Nobre](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/64199).

#### Usando push

Já que você citou `push` na pergunta, aqui vão alguns exemplos com esse método:

```
// Primeiro você cria a array, depois dá push dos valores
var a = [];
a.push('dado1', 'dado2');

// O resultado é o mesmo de usar arrays literais:
var b = ['dado1','dado2'];
var c = ['dado1','dado2'];

// Embrulhando tudo em outra array
var arr = [];
arr.push(a, b, c);
```

Nota: arrays não são do jQuery, fazem parte da linguagem JavaScript (na qual o jQuery é escrito).

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer algo assim:

```
var options = { 
    size: ["S", "M", "L", "XL", "XXL"],
    color: ["Red", "Blue", "Green", "White", "Black"]
};
```

Para acessar cada chave individualmente:

```
for (var key in options) {
    alert(key);
}
```

Comment: Eduardo Nobre eu tentei implementar a sua lógica mas sem sucesso esse link foi até onde eu consegui fazer. De uma olha e depois vc me fala algo sobre: https://jsfiddle.net/u49zt8wr/3/